# How do I use the SQL IN statement to get MS Access to connect to another MS Access database?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to use MS Access to query an MS Access database that is not the current database. I am using:

```
SELECT [tblA].[fieldA]
FROM [tblA]
IN "G:\path\databaseA" "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
WHERE ((([tblA].[fieldA])="30000"));
```

Running this query returns the error `Could not find installable ISAM.`

I thought the connect string might not be necessary when connecting to another MS Access database (extension .mdb) so I also tried:

```
SELECT [tblA].[fieldA]
FROM [tblA]
IN "G:\path\databaseA.mdb"
WHERE ((([tblA].[fieldA])="30000"));
```

However, this returns the error "The text file specification does not exist. You cannot import, export, or link using the specification."

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Don't you need the full path? something .mdb, alternatively link the foreign table

Comment: I tried including the file extension .mdb but the result was the same. I am not sure what you mean by link the foreign table.

Comment: I have confirmed that the path exists and that db includes tblA. Running a simpler query: `SELECT * FROM tblA IN 'G:\path\databaseA.mdb'` results in the same error: "The text file specification '2010 Link Specification' does not exist. You cannot import, export, or link using the specification."

Comment: I don't understand why Access complains about *'2010 Link Specification'*.  Where and how are you attempting to use that `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Maybe there's already a Spec file assigned to it?  Those things can be tricky.  Try creating a new, empty Access DB and running that query.  See if you get the same error.

Comment: I tried that and the same error came up. If I open databaseA.mdb in Access and then run the full query everything is fine. I dont know if this helps Access to find the Spec file or if it is just because databaseA is already open and Access doesn't need to go looking for it. However, if I open databaseA.mdb and then try to run the same query but with a second database, databaseB.mdb I get the same error except the error now reads  "The text file specification '2011 Link Specification' does not exist. You cannot import, export, or link using the specification."

Comment: databaseA is 2010 data and databaseB is 2011 data.

Comment: In reply to HansUp: I am using the SELECT statement in the SQL View of a MS Access query design.

Comment: @LucasParker I can't reproduce that "text file specification" issue with a standard desktop database.  Are you perhaps dealing with an Access 2010 web database?

Comment: @HansUp The database is stored on a remote computer on my local network.

Comment: @HansUp When you use `IN 'G:\path\databaseA.mdb'` do you need to enter a connect string or any other type of specification?

Comment: No.  If the remote db file is valid and a version which the db engine can use, it will use it.  You don't supply a "Provider" property, a connection string, or anything other than the path to the db file.  At least that has been my experience these past 10 years.  However, you're encountering a complaint about a specification file ... which is something I've never seen for an Access query.  I'm stumped.

Comment: @HansUp I tried pasting some of the data into a new MA Access database and saving it as databaseC.mdb. I can run the query `SELECT * FROM tblA IN 'G:\path\databaseC.mdb` without problem. Somehow, the databaseA.mdb file is causing the text file specification issue. Thanks for your help. I'll let you know if I figure this out.

Comment: @HansUp I found the problem. databaseA.mdb is made up of a bunch of linked tables. The tables are linked to fixed width text files and the "text file specifications" are the specifications that were used to read the text file data into Access. The issue seems to be that Access is unable to pull data from linked tables when the command `SELECT * FROM tblA IN 'G:\path\databaseC.mdb` is used. Any thoughts on a better way of doing this?

Comment: Recreate the links in the db you have open when you're running the query.  Then, with *tblA* as a link in the current db, your query can be just `SELECT * FROM tblA;`